# Rails (validate: false) except one attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way to do `object.save(validate: false)` specifying an attribute that we actually want to validate?

So, for example, for the User model, I want to `validate: false` except for the name that I want it validated.

Comment: what is your use-case?

Answer (score 1):

How I am doing it:

I only need validation for 1 attribute of `User` model. But I am not using `User` model for this validation.

I created `AutoRegisterUser` model only for validation.

```rb
class AutoRegisterUser < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'users'

  attr_accessor :business_booking

  validates :email,
    presence: true,
    format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP, message: 'has invalid format' }

  validates :email, uniqueness: { message: 'has already been taken' }
end
```

Here I am using `self.table_name = 'users'` database table. so, I can check `uniqueness` validation from `users`database table.

Now, I can validate like this:

```rb
user = AutoRegisterUser.new({ email: 'example@gmail.com'})
user.valid?
user.save # it will be saved to "users" database table
```

I hope this solution helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

A convoluted way would be to do `object.save` without validation, then use `update` to update the attribute which should be validated. All other validations would be skipped and only your required attribute would be validated:

```
# save all other attributes other than the one that needs validation
object.assign_attributes params.except(:required_attribute)
object.save validate: false

if object.persisted?
  # update the attribute which requires validation
  object.update required_attribute: params[:required_attribute]

  if ! object.valid?
    # handle validation error
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Rails' [Object#with_options](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/Object:with_options) and [conditional validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation):

On your model definition:

```rb
  attr_accessor :exclusive_name_validation

  with_options unless: -> {exclusive_name_validation.present?} do
   # All validations you don't want
  end


  validates_presence_of :the_name_you_always_validate
```

Then you can pass in the option:

```rb
object.save(exclusive_name_validation: true)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the conditions on which you need to do so, but an obvious solution could be to overwrite the `save` method or create an additional one doing this single validation.

```
class User
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :other_attribute, presence: true

  def my_custom_save
    save(validate: false) if has_valid_name?
  end

  private

  def has_valid_name?
    valid? || errors.messages.keys.exclude?(:name)
  end 
end
```